# How does the placement of a concept definition change program behaviour

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I'm compiling this code with `gcc 9.3` with `-fconcepts`.

The following compiles successfully

```
void f(int) {}             // 1

template<typename T>       // 2 
concept C = requires (T a) 
{ { f(a) }; };

template<C T>              // 3
void g() { f(42); }

int main() { g<int>(); }   // 4
```

However, if I define the function `f` *after* I define the concept `C`,

```
template<typename T>       // 2 
concept C = requires (T a) 
{ { f(a) }; };

void f(int) {}             // 1

template<C T>              // 3
void g() { f(42); }

int main() { g<int>(); }   // 4
```

then the program fails to compile with

```
error:
line 4: cannot call function g
because
line 3: constraint not satisfied
because
line 2: required expression f(a) would be ill-formed
```

This seems odd, since by the time `g<int>` needs to be instantiated, the definition of `f` should be visible. Could someone explain what's going on here?

Note that if I declare `f` before the concept definition, then even if I define `f` afterwards, the program compiles successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) doesn't apply to `int`, so `f(a)` (with `int a`) is ill formed when not declared before.

You will have similar issue with:

```
void f(int){}

template<typename T>
void g(T t)
{
    f(t);
}
void f(char){}

void h() { g('*'); } // Call f(int)
```

Comment: So if I understand what you're saying, in the body of `g`, ADL will only consider functions that have been declared before it?

Comment: ADL doesn't apply to fundamental types. It applies roughly for class/template classes adding their namespace for the look-up.