# How to avoid this nasty concept trap (depending on order)

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-warnings, c++20, c++-concepts

The following code depends on whether the concept is defined *before* or *after* the class. The intent is to check, whether a `Quantity` can be constructed from a `T`. I have stripped this down, only showing the test for copy construction.

```
template <typename T>
concept is_compatible = requires( T & t ) { Quantity( t ); }; // note: not Quantity<T> !

template <typename T>
class Quantity
{};

class X{};        

int main() 
{

    std::cout << is_compatible<Quantity<X>>;
    std::cout << is_compatible<X>;
}
```

With the given code, the output is 00, not the intended 10. To get the intended result, the concept has to be defined *after* the class.

I would have expected one of two things for the code above:

1. It just works as intended
2. A warning or error is given by the compiler (to hint at our mistake, if it is one) Note that when using e.g. `Quantity<T>` instead of `Quantity` in the concept, a compiler error is issued, because `Quantity<T>` does not make sense at that point.

I would not have expected the third, silent option! There might be a "good reason" for this, "because compilers work a certain way", but I find this pretty flawed.

What would be a better way to write this code, if the behaviour is correct?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019722/how-does-the-placement-of-a-concept-definition-change-program-behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There might be a "good reason" for this, "because compilers work a certain way", but I find this pretty flawed.

Concepts wouldn't be as useful without it. You wouldn't be able to check that a function call expression relying on ADL is valid. Your concept is satisfied by this pair of declarations

```
namespace ns {
    struct X {};
    void Quantity(X) {}
}
```

And it will be satisfied even if `is_compatible` is defined before `ns`.

Now, if your concept has nothing to do with ADL, and your expression is indeed intended to be a function-styled cast, then simply qualify the type (or template name)

```
template <typename T>
concept is_compatible = requires( T & t ) { ::Quantity( t ); };
                                          // ^ -- in the absence of a preceding declaration, error here
```

Comment: Yeah, figured that `Quantity` could be any function shortly after writing the question. Still, I don't understand why the "ADL phase" will not find the copy constructor, if it can find any function... sigh.

Comment: @non-user - ADL only finds free functions

Comment: Sure, back to school *facepalm*. Funny thing about the `::Quantity`: gcc (of course) correctly issues the error if it precedes the class. MSVC (the compiler understanding the simple man) compiles and does the expected thing in both cases. However, intellisense still squiggles the error - both before or after. It's a messy world. (Yes, I know concepts are not ready yet)

Comment: I hated this 'check for copy constructor/conversion' to begin with, what I really wanted to do was just check if `T` already is a `Quantity`.

Comment: @non-user - MSVC's handling of templates is non-standard by default. You have to turn off permissive mode explicitly to get a semblence of standard conformance. As for checking if `T` is a `Quantity` specialization, that can be done with a simple type trait (even in C++98). The concept need only wrap that.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Actually, there's a concept for that too: `is_same`.

Comment: Thx. Just fell back to a trait 3min ago. Wanted to avoid it this time for maximum simplicity, but that did not go too well. ||| I'm on `/permissive-` for a while now, good hint in general. Still, there are differences.

Comment: @NicolBolas : If you could teach me how to use it (i.e. `is_same`) for a templated class...

Comment: @non-user38741: Now you seem to be talking about a different question. Which is "is this type the result of instantiation from this template". That's not the same thing as telling whether one type is another. And there are questions on SO about detecting that. That being said, it's probably best to avoid asking that question entirely. Don't tell users what templates they must specialize; tell them what interface they have to provide. Concepts aren't base classes; don't treat them like one.